# Property 'RecaptchaVerifier' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am implementing code for phone authentication using firebase, ionic + angularjs but i am getting error in RecaptchaVerifier
**My TS file**

```
constructor(
private afauth: AngularFireAuth,
private windowService: WindowService,
private auth: AngularFireModule;  )  { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.windowRef = this.windowService.windowRef;
  {
    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new this.afauth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: () => {
        this.disableOTPsendbutton = true;
      }
    });
    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier.render();
   }
}

sendOTP() {
  this.afauth.signInWithPhoneNumber(this.phoneNumber, this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier)
    .then((confirmationResult) =>
    {
      this.windowRef.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
    }).catch(err => console.log('err1', err));
}
```

I am getting error in line:

```
this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier = new this.afauth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
```

Error showing in vs code is:

> Property 'RecaptchaVerifier' does not exist on type 'AngularFireAuth'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a div for recaptcha container like below

```
<div class='ion-center'
          style="position:relative;z-index:10;width:100%;margin-top:2em;margin-left:2em;margin-right:auto;">
          <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
        </div>
```

Try installing firebase package from npm

```
npm install firebase --save
```

and then import it in your page.ts file like

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

replace your afauth with firebase.auth like

```
this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier=await new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container',{'size':'invisible'});
```

Your ngOnInit should be like

```
ngOnInit {
this.windowRef=await this.windowService.windowRef;
    this.windowRef.recaptchaVerifier=await new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container',{'size':'invisible'});
}
```